# How to use the value of a cell to write a formula in the same cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, recursion

I have a spreadsheet here. On Cell J2, I need to write a formula, but the problem is that I can't overwrite the cell as it contains the value which are to be needed for the formula. I can't add a new column as it is the requirement. I need to write the following formula on **J2** using the current value of J2.
`=IF(ISBLANK(H2),"((TODAY()-(F2))*24)-(G2)",J2)`

The left columns are intentionally kept blank as I am not supposed to share those information. However those are not necessary for the calculations.

How I am supposed to do it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TH6Pf.png)

Comment: Excel could not allow a formula refers to its own cell, it would be circular reference.

Comment: Unless you can enter the value into the formula instead of the cell reference, using a macro or helper column would be the way.

Answer (score 1):

> but the problem is that I can't overwrite the cell as it contains the value which are to be needed for the formula

This is how Excel works, it can not hold both value and formula in the same cell.

You can use macro to replace value in the cell based on conditions, but when the value is replaced it's lost, you won't be able to restore it.